# CISCO 2948 instead of 2950 for CCNAS

Tags: cisco

I'm building a CCNA/CCNAS lab, I can get my hands on some cheap 2948 level 3 switches.

I  was wondering if they also can be used for the CCNAS labs as I always see the 2950 mentioned for these. Are there any features that the 2950 has that the 2948 doesn't have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2950's are painted in light Cisco blue. 2948's aren't. Go ahead and use the 2948.

To be less tongue-in-cheek, you'll be able to do anything (and then a bit more on L3) with the 2948 than the 2950. I can't think of a reason to not use them. I'd throw in one 2950 just to have the variety and catch students who somehow get lost in the L2/L3 separation.

Answer (score 1):

2948G-L3s are extremely old (over 10 years) and extremely feature limited.  They don't support a lot of things you would expect, and are, hardware wise, a mismash of really old IOS switches with the routing "brains" from a 8500 ATM switch router option card.  When they have hardware failures, they can even send out syslogs about ATM cell failures.  I'd look at 2600s instead - at least you can get code for them that will support most routing protocols and features correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, no.

The 2948 doesn't support IOS, only CatOS, so this isn't going to help at all in CCNA study because the commands can be very different. I happen to have a 2948 beside me - there is no IOS upgrade for them.

I would suggest you use the 2950s for CCNA and see if you can get a cheap 26x1 router from eBay. Make sure it's an x1 as 26x0 has only one Ethernet port.